# Allow user to edit only some of the fields on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I achieve that an user could only edit some fields from a record?

For example:

A user can register on the system and select and specify username, password, etc. But a registered user can only edit his name, email and password, not his username.

I have a partial _form, which I use for new and edit functions.
The partial looks like this:

```
    <% form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <p>
            <%= f.label :gruebl_employee_id %><br />
            <%= f.collection_select(:firma_employee_id, FirmaEmployee.find(:all).sort_by{|p| p.lastname.downcase},:id,:full_name, {  :include_blank => "---keine Mitarbeiter---", :prompt => "---Bitte auswählen---"}, { :style => "width: 332px;"}) %>
        </p>
         <%= observe_field(:user_firma_employee_id,
         :frequency => 0.25,
         :url => { :action => :retrieveinfo },
         :with => "'id='+value") %>

        <p>
          <%= f.label :username %><br />
          <%= f.text_field :username %>
        </p>

         <p>
          <%= f.label :admin, "Administrator ?" %><br />
          <%= f.check_box :admin %>
        </p>

        <p>
          <%= f.label :email %><br />
          <%= f.text_field :email %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :password %><br />
          <%= f.password_field :password %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
        </p>
        <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<%end%>
```

What I am trying to do is block the user from changing the employee and the username attribute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? Can you post your edit partial?

Comment: <% form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

Comment: sorry.. you will find the partial on the edited question.. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take care of this in several places.

First, use attr_accessible in the User model, to include only those you want the user to edit:

`attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation #...`

Then in the form partial, only shows the username field when showing the signup form:

```
<% if @user.new_record? %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
<% end %>
```

Lastly, in the create action, manually set the username field, since it's now in the attr_accessible list you cannot mass assign it:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.username = params[:user][:username]
```

Please keep in mind if username is able to be set through mass assignment, even if you disable the username field in the form, it still can be modified (it's easy to change the field value in the form on the client side). That's why we have to use the attr_accessible for pretection.

Edit: noticed your partial, it's better to protect the admin field as username, otherwise users are able to set themselves as admin by changing the fields value on client side.

Comment: i will try it, but i had some problems already with the attr_accessible  when creating new records. i mean if the attribute is not listed there its also not taken in count when creating first time the record..

Comment: ah thats why you assign it manually.. ok ok.. will test everything. :) thanks!

Comment: @JamesChen hi thank you for your answer - are you able to elaborate on this point: "That's why we have to use the attr_accessible for pretection."? In other words, given the form exists how do we stop users from mass assigning?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you have two ways of doing this.

1 - Use the html support for making the textbox readonly. So in your case, user_name textbox will be something like this

```
<input type="text" name="user_name" value="<User Name>" readonly="readonly" />
```

2 - But I prefer doing something like creating a read-only textbox in your rails application helper can calling it as and when required

So the example would be

in my application helper

```
module ApplicationHelper

    def read_only_text_field(object_name, method, options = {})
          text_field(object_name, method, :disabled => true)
    end
end
```

and in my view I have

```
<%= read_only_text_field :user, :user_name %>
```

I think its more DRY/ Railly way.

** IMPORTANT - and make sure you doent count the read-only value from your controllers when saving etc.. By that way, even a user changes these readonly values you are still out of the trouble :D

hope this helps

cheers

sameera

Comment: ok ive thought about it, creating a different partial for edit action with the option "disabled" like you said. but is there any way to block the edit from such fields, maybe from the controller or the model itself, to make it more secure? thanks

Comment: Hi user617483, in that case, instead of making the textbox read only , just make it a lable. As per my example helper method, update it to return a label insted of the read only textbox. To make it sure As i said, ignore those values when updating :D

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use "object" in conjunction with a label for anything you don't want to change. Here is how you should code it for the username:

```
<%= f.label(:username, f.object.username) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my related solution to a similar problem - we have fields that we want a user to be able to set themselves, we don't require them on creation of the record, but we do NOT want to them be changed once they are set.

```rb
  validate :forbid_changing_some_field, on: :update

  def forbid_changing_some_field
    return unless some_field_changed?
    return if some_field_was.nil?

    self.some_field = some_field_was
    errors.add(:some_field, 'can not be changed!')
  end
```

The thing that surprised me, though, was that `update_attribute` still works, it bypasses the validations.  Not a huge deal, since updates to the record are mass assigned in practice - but I called that out in the tests to make it clear.  Here's some tests for it.

```
    describe 'forbids changing some field once set' do
      let(:initial_some_field) { 'initial some field value' }
      it 'defaults as nil' do
        expect(record.some_field).to be nil
      end

      it 'can be set' do
        expect {
          record.update_attribute(:some_field, initial_some_field)
        }.to change {
          record.some_field
        }.from(nil).to(initial_some_field)
      end

      describe 'once it is set' do
        before do
          record.update_attribute(:some_field, initial_some_field)
        end

        it 'makes the record invalid if changed' do
          record.some_field = 'new value'
          expect(record).not_to be_valid
        end

        it 'does not change in mass update' do
          expect {
            record.update_attributes(some_field: 'new value')
          }.not_to change {
            record.some_field
          }.from(initial_some_field)
        end

        it 'DOES change in update_attribute!! (skips validations' do
          expect {
            record.update_attribute(:some_field, 'other new value')
          }.to change {
            record.some_field
          }.from(initial_some_field).to('other new value')
        end
      end
    end
```